# Verificar numero de clicks em botões

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho um script com funções para controlar o que cada botão de uma aplicação faz. Declarei uma variável global para que, quando todos os botões forem clicados, seja despoletado duas ações: ocultar uma div e mostrar outra.

```
//variável global

var completo = 0;

//funções para controlar 9 botões - em cada uma das funções incremento a variável:

function A()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
}
function B()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
} 
function C()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
} 
function D()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
} 
function E()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
} 
function F()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
} 
function G()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
}
function H()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
} 
function I()
{
     faz qualquer coisa;
     completo++
}
```

Até aqui deveria incrementar 9 vezes a variável completo, ficando completo=9, certo?

Então de seguida iria despoletar ação - quando a variável chegar a 9, ocultar a div geral e mostrar div final.

```
if(completo==9)
{
    $('div[id^="final"]').show();
    $('div[id^="geral"]').hide();
}
```

esta ultima parte não está funcional.

também já testei com o seguinte, mas sem sucesso:

```
if(completo==9)
{
    $("#final").show();
    $("#geral").hide();
}
```

conseguem ajudar-me?

Na parte do html tenho declarada tanto a div geral como a div final:

```
<div id="geral">"conteudo blablabla"</div>
<div id="final">"conteudo blablabla"</div>
```

Comment: Qual é o código que chama essas funcões A, B, C, ...? Não vejo onde essas funcões sejam chamadas e o `completo` é sempre zero...

Comment: O código do botão que chama o conteúdo da função é:

<td><input type="button" class="astext" value="D" onclick="A()"/></td>

Comment: Ok, então dentro de cada funcão tens de chamar outra funcão que tem o `if` dentro. Se não esse `if` só é verificado quando a página carrega e nunca mais. Faz sentido?

Comment: Fora o problema que o @Sergio apontou, isso tudo parte do princípio de que cada botão só pode ser apertado uma vez, certo? Porque se permitir mais de um clique por botão, sua lógica não vai funcionar (bastaria por exemplo apertar 9 vezes um único botão para cumprir a condição).

Comment: bfavaretto, correcto, essa parte ainda será avaliada a seguir. Para já estou empenhado em colocar isto funcional! :)
Sergio, obrigado pela dica, excelente!

Answer (score 1):

O que o Sergio disse esta correto... Lembre-se que o JS só e carregado uma vez na sua pagina, então deve ter uma função que verifique se sua variável global atingiu os 9 eventos de `click`...

---

### Js Puro:

```
function A(){
    teste();
}

function B(){
    teste();
}

function C(){
    teste();
}

function D(){
    teste();
}

function E(){
    completo++;
    teste();
}

function F(){
    teste();
}

function G(){
    teste();
}

function H(){
    teste();
}

function I(){
    teste();
}

function teste(){
    completo++;

    if(completo==9){
        document.getElementById("geral").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("final").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

Outra solução seria se aproveitar do `JQuery` utilizado na sua pagina e colocar a função que verifica a variável "global" dentro do `ready` da pagina, desse modo:

---

### JQuery

```
var completo = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(":button").click(function() {
        completo++;
        $(this).hide();

        if(completo==9){
            $('div[id^="final"]').show();
            $('div[id^="geral"]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Utilizando essa segunda implementação você consegue esconder o botão que acionou o evento do `click` com essa linha: `$(this).hide();`

Comment: Marcelo, Obrigado! Contudo não estou a conseguir que, chegado ao 9, esconda uma div e mostre a outra :/
Desculpem algumas questões, ainda estou a iniciar...

Comment: editei o código @lfprata, com uma função que esconde o botão que foi clicado, uma alternativa seria apenas deixar o botão desabilitado

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio correcto, agora sim, já faz algo! Muito obrigado. Terei no entanto de alterar a propriedade da div "final" uma vez que você colocou também como hidden - a ideia seria mostrar essa, correcto?

Comment: @lfprata agora que você veio com essa duvida, parece que entendi qual era o real problema, verifique se você esta referenciando a biblioteca do `JQuery`... as funções `$('div[id^="final"]').show();` e `$('div[id^="geral"]').hide();` necessitam da biblioteca do `JQuery` para funcionar